# Fraction with complex exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, fractions

I want to solve for $\gamma$ in the following equation:

> $$
> \frac{1-e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}}{1+e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}}=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}
> $$

*Attempt:*
\begin{align}
1-e^{-2\cdot10^{-3}\gamma}&=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}(1+e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma})
\\
&=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}+1.54e^{i0.24\pi}e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
1-e^{-2\cdot10^{-3}\gamma}-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
1-e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
(-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi})
=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
-e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
(-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi})
=1.54e^{i0.24\pi}-1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
(-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi})
=-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}+1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
e^{-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma}
=
\frac{-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}+1}{-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}}
\end{align}
Stuck with this fraction, how can I simplify it?
\begin{align}
-2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma
=
\ln \bigg (\frac{-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}+1}{-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}}\bigg )
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\gamma
=\frac{1}{-2\cdot 10^{-3}}
\ln \bigg (\frac{-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}+1}{-1-1.54e^{i0.24\pi}}\bigg )
\end{align}

*Correct answer is approximately:*
$$
2\cdot 10^{-3}\gamma=\ln (2.24 e^{i0.68\pi})
$$
$$
\gamma= 0.0403+i0.108=0.115 e^{i0.386\pi}
$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use $e^{i\theta }=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta $, and then multiply and divide by the conjugate of denominator to simplify further.

---

By the way, it would have been easier to solve, if you had introduced another variables, I.e.

$$e^{-2 \times 10^{-3} \gamma}=t ; \quad 1.54 e^{i 0.24\pi} =k$$

Now rewrite the equation as $$\frac{1-t}{1+t}=k \implies^{\text{(C & D)}} \; t =\frac{1-k}{k+1}$$

And now substitue in terms of $\gamma$ back into obtained equation.